# Images Uploading PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I've been working on a project that is relevantly easier than what it took me to do it.

I made an entire website that is between doctors and patients;
I'm badly stuck in uploading and retrieving images!!

Here is the code I've been building..

```css
<?php session_start();

$un = "xxx";
$pw = "xxx";
$hn = "xxx";
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hn, $un, $pw) or die("Couldn't connect to the database");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$selected = mysql_select_db("dsnnet_login", $dbhandle);
$myusername = $_SESSION['snamed'];


$target_dir = "uploaded/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE docTable set photoname='$target_file' WHERE Username= '$myusername'");
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

header("location: docp.php");

?>
```

and the "working page" is as follow:

```css
<?php session_start();

$un = "xxx";
$pw = "xxx";
$hn = "xxx";
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hn, $un, $pw) or die("Couldn't connect to the database");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$selected = mysql_select_db("dsnnet_login", $dbhandle);
$myusername = $_SESSION['snamed'];


$target_dir = "uploaded/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE docTable set photoname='$target_file' WHERE Username= '$myusername'");
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

header("location: docp.php");

?>
```

Can anyone help me figure it out?
I've been trying for at least 4 days now..
I'm not giving up.. I'm open to learn..

thank you guys:)
cheers

Comment: are you getting any errors while uploading like the one mentioned -Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed. or Sorry, your file is too large.

Answer (score 1):

**check below**

1.tag form have enctype="multipart/form-data"

2.if not localhost ,folder upload must set permittion 777

Answer (score 1):

May I know error message which make you stuck?

before that, please check your form enctype attribute. Your upload form must be :

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```